# UIAlert View With UIActivity Indicator - Only Shows Activity Once

Tags: ios, swift, uialertview, uiactivityindicatorview

I have function that shows an alert view with a `UIActivityIndictor`

```
var alert = UIAlertView()

Class AlertWithSpinner: NSObject {

    class func alertSpinnerWithTitle (titleText: String, messageText: String){

        alert.title = titleText
        alert.message = messageText

        var alertSubView:UIView = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(83,-10,100,40))
        var loadingIndicator: UIActivityIndicatorView = UIActivityIndicatorView(frame: CGRectMake(50, 10, 37, 37)) as UIActivityIndicatorView
        loadingIndicator.center = alertSubView.center
        loadingIndicator.hidesWhenStopped = true
        loadingIndicator.activityIndicatorViewStyle = UIActivityIndicatorViewStyle.Gray
        loadingIndicator.startAnimating();
        alertSubView.addSubview(loadingIndicator)
        alert.setValue(alertSubView, forKey: "accessoryView")
        loadingIndicator.startAnimating()

        alert.show()

    }

   class func dismiss(){

        alert.dismissWithClickedButtonIndex(-1, animated: true)

    }
 }
```

The first presentation of the alert is fine.  All subsequent presentations do not show the `UIActivityIndicator`, just the `UIAlert`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the best way to achieve this - use external libraries with similar functionality:

[SVProgressHUD](https://github.com/TransitApp/SVProgressHUD)

[MBProgressHUD](https://github.com/jdg/MBProgressHUD)

Answer (score 0):

You should create your own alert in case you want to modify it. From [Apple Docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIAlertView_Class/)

> The UIAlertView class is intended to be used as-is and does not support subclassing. The view hierarchy for this class is private and must not be modified.

Answer (score 0):

You are reusing your UIAlertView so the first UIActivityIndicatorView is still a subview of the alert.
Add the following line to remove the old UIActivityIndicatorView right after setting the message of your UIAlertView.

```
if alert.subviews.count > 0 {
   alert.subviews[0].removeFromSuperview()
}
```

Comment: Still the same, makes no diference

Comment: Make sure you are executing your code in the main thread otherwise the UI will not change. Use "performSelectorOnMainThread" or similar. Could you also post the code where you are removing from superview?